# Simufact / MARC and Fortran

Tags: finite-element-method, simulation, numerical-methods

I am using Simufact from MSC Software to perform numerical simulations.
To be able to create my own sub-routines I need to have Fortran compiler installed.
Simufact manual mentions only Intel Fortran + Visual Studio. Both of them are really expensive to purchase.
I wil lbe guessing, the same method can be used for Marc and Fortran coupling
Is there a way to use open-source compilers for that? Can you guide me in this matter?
Thank you.

Comment: I have had this problem 4 years ago as well, in 2015. don't have hope in them. nothing is changed so far then, why would you really need subroutines ? what is your application to simulate ?

Comment: I would like to use custom procedures to create my own optimization projects with multiple variables. At the moment, the software makes all possible combinations of the variables while I would like to create something like Monte Carlo simulations.